# Macro psGTriangle leads to pdfLatex ignoring the figure

Tags: xetex, pdftex, pstricks, auto-pst-pdf, pdfcrop

I've noticed that the pstricks macro psGTriangle, to draw triangles with Gouraud shading does not work in combination with auto-pst-pdf/pdflatex. 
There is no error message, the pspicture environment is just ignored. 
Here is minimal example to illustrate the problem :

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pstricks,pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.5cm}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-5,-5)(5,5)
  \psGTriangle(-2,-2)(3,-1)(-0.5,3){red}{white}{blue}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-5,-5)(5,5)
  \psline(-3,-2)(4,3)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Compiling this example with latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf gives a pdf with both pspictures environment.

```
latex pdfmini.tex && dvips pdfmini.dvi && ps2pdf pdfmini.ps pdfmini_latex.pdf
```

Compiling the same example with pdflatex gives a pdf with 2 blank pages  and the second pspicture environment on a third page.

```
pdflatex -shell-escape pdfmini.tex
```

Looking in the generated *pdfmini-pics.pdf* file, it is visible that something is wrong with the figure containing the psGTriangle, even if it is displayed.
It seems that some how the crop did not work really fine .

During my research to solve this problem, it appeared that compiling with xelatex renders a good pdf file. However I use the psGTriangle macro in a bigger document, and i'd rather stay with pdflatex (since I'm really not familiar with the xelatex).

Is this problem known, solvable, or do I have to live with it ?

Thank you for your help.

Edit :
@percusse:  I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with

- texlive version 2012.20120611-3~ubuntu12.04.1.
- pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
- XeTeX 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)

Comment: Both Xe- and pdf- TeX works fine on my system (MikTeX 2.9 SumartaPDF and AcroRead X).

Comment: Use `[crop=off]`, see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a suggestion. Put your drawing code in a separate, compilable input file as follows.

```
% figure.tex
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\psset{unit=0.5cm}

\begin{document}
% figure-1
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-5,-5)(5,5)
  \psGTriangle(-2,-2)(3,-1)(-0.5,3){red}{white}{blue}
\end{pspicture}
% figure-2
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-5,-5)(5,5)
  \psline(-3,-2)(4,3)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Compile `figure.tex` with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` sequence to obtain a PDF containing some pages. Each page represent a single diagram.

From your main input file, import the PDF images with `\includegraphics` (from `graphicx` package) as follows.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\Insert[2][1]{\includegraphics[scale=#1,page=#2]{figure}}

\begin{document}
\Insert{1}

\Insert{2}
\end{document}
```

Compile the `main.tex` with `pdflatex`.

### Simulation

The following code simulates the above scenario in a single file. Compile it with `pdflatex -shell-escape simulation.tex`.

```
% simulation.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{figure.tex}
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\psset{unit=0.5cm}

\begin{document}
% figure-1
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-5,-5)(5,5)
  \psGTriangle(-2,-2)(3,-1)(-0.5,3){red}{white}{blue}
\end{pspicture}
% figure-2
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-5,-5)(5,5)
  \psline(-3,-2)(4,3)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\foreach \compiler/\ext in {latex/tex,dvips/dvi,{ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None}/ps}{\immediate\write18{\compiler\space figure.\ext}}


\newcommand\Insert[2][1]{\includegraphics[scale=#1,page=#2]{figure}}
\begin{document}
\Insert{1}

\Insert{2}
\end{document}
```

### Note

`ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None figure.ps` is used to prevent the `ps2pdf` from automatically changing the page orientation. The simple example simulating the case in which `ps2pdf` automatically rotates the page is given as follows.

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](4,4)% grid must be disabled
    \rput{90}(2,2){PSTricks}% the text should be rotated by 90 ccw
\end{pspicture}
```

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. It solves my problem, even if I still don't understand why it does not work with the auto-pst-pdf package.

Comment: @AdamB.: Sorry. I don't know why as I don't use `auto-pst-pdf` that is not suitable for a long document project economically (wasting much time to compile unchanged PSTricks code).

Answer (score 2):

use

```
\documentclass{minimal}    
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}%%%%%%%

\begin{document}    
\psset{unit=0.5cm}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
  \psGTriangle(-2,-2)(3,-1)(-0.5,3){red}{white}{blue}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
  \psline(-3,-2)(4,3)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

in some special cases the `pdfcrop` command fails.

Comment: Indeed it solves the problem. Thank you for your help. Can you give more details about those special cases where pdfcrop fails ?

Comment: If you have no Perl installed then you also need that option. The other cases are very rare, so that I cannot remember.